# Compiling error in Spring application

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a Spring tutorial. The code is supposed to instantiate the Catalog JavaBean and invoke its methods without the method interceptor. The Catalog bean is to be instantiated using the  elements in beanDefinition.xml. I am getting an error in SpringClient.java that says some files are not visible, well these files are declared private in Catalog.java so that's understandable in a typical Java program,but I thought the beanDefinition.xml and the line `Catalog catalog = (Catalog) context.getBean("spring.catalog");` in SpringClient.java would take care of things. I am not exactly sure why I am getting these errors and I am quite new to Spring. The code can be obtained [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t4bw19aspfvbd4y/AABp_Kn5j1wAN-203gX4lov_a?dl=0). Hope someone can help. 
[image: IDE screen]

Answer (score 0):

At which line in SpringClient.java? The compiler error tells what's wrong there clearly.

I see you're accessing Catalog **private** instance variable there directly. If this is the line, change it: use getter or change visibility.

Comment: I am aware of the private declaration and that it is causing the problem and I know that either changing the visibility or using getter will solve it. This happens to be a spring application, which I am new to and I was wondering if there could be something in Spring which is supposed to circumvent this. This code is not written by me, it's from the book "Java EE Development with Eclipse" from packt publishing.

Comment: Nope. Spring doesn't provide anything like this. it is definitely an error in the code there. you may email the author about this..